# Debugging the following function (Segment fault error)

Tags: c

Is there anything wrong with the following functions?. Somehow, they are creating a segment fault.

```
struct processNode* create_node()
{
    struct processNode* newNode =  (struct processNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct processNode));
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

struct processNode* append_node(struct processNode* list,struct processNode* newNode )
{
    struct processNode* tracker= NULL;
    tracker = list;

    if(tracker == NULL)
    {
        tracker = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        while(tracker->next != NULL)
        {
            tracker =tracker->next;
        }
        tracker->next = newNode;
        tracker = tracker->next;
    }

    tracker->next=NULL;
    tracker = list;
    return tracker;
}
```

I am creating a shell in C and need to create a link list to parse the command lines from the user. In the second function, I intend to return a new list with the new appended pointer;

Comment: Consider `list` as NULL. Now walk that function. *Carefully*. What do you think `tracker = list` does (note: it appears *twice* in that function; once in the `if` block, one *after* the `else` block). Hmmm.

Comment: Have you actually tried to run this in a debugger (as per the title of your question)? That should show you where things go wrong. I also find valgrind a useful tool for these issues, since it'll be likely a memory allocation gone wrong.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the function shall return a pointer to the head of the list.

Assume the function is called with `list` being `NULL`

So this is fine:

```
    if(tracker == NULL)
    {
      tracker = newNode;
    }
```

but here

```
    tracker = list;   <---- Not good....
    return tracker;
```

You overwrite tracker and return NULL

You could try like:

```
struct processNode* append_node(struct processNode* list,struct processNode* newNode )
{
    struct processNode* tracker= NULL;
    tracker = list;

    if(tracker == NULL)
    {
        tracker = newNode;
        return tracker;        // Notice
    }

    while(tracker->next != NULL)
    {
        tracker =tracker->next;
    }
    tracker->next = newNode;

    return list; 
}
```

Comment: "you overwrite tracker and return null", umm how is that possible. List_head is the same pointer and tracker works on the same list_head is pointing to, so if I set tracker = list_head at the end, how is that a problem?

Comment: @Daniel `tracker` and `list` are **not** the same pointer. They are different pointers. Changing `tracker` does **not** change `list`. So if your function is called with `list` being `NULL`, the function returns `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

The following cases will give you seg fault here on line `tracker->next=NULL;`:

1. `tracker != NULL && newNode == NULL`
2. `tracker == NULL`

   ```
       ....
   tracker = tracker->next;
   }

   //THE FOLLOWING LINE WILL CAUSE PROBLEM
   tracker->next=NULL; 
   tracker = list;
   return tracker;
    ....
   }
   ```

You can do like this:

```
struct processNode* append_node(struct processNode* list,struct processNode* newNode )
{
    struct processNode* tracker= NULL;
    tracker = list;

     if(!newNode){
        //Do nothing 
     }          
    else if(tracker == NULL)
    {
        tracker = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        while(tracker->next != NULL)
        {
            tracker = tracker->next;
        }
        tracker->next = newNode;
        tracker = tracker->next;
    }

    return tracker;
}
```